# .Net Rx First and last item in a period of time

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

We have a chart that user can drag. On mouse move we have an event that sets a property that triggers OnNext with new and old value (this is needed elsewhere).

```
public double Value
{
    get { return _value; }
    set
    {
        if(ShouldUpdate && value!=_value)
            _subject.OnNext(factoryMethod(this, value, _value, Index));
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

I need to get first and last item of the  dragging. By last item I'd assume if there is a pause of 250 ms between events.

i.e. User start to drag first event is being stored next events are coming up. When he stops to drag and no new events are showing up for 250ms a subscribe is being called that contains list of two elements first and last.
When user starts to drag again new first and last are being created (I don't care about old values).

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to get first and last item of the dragging"?

Comment: Can you show your complete code?

Comment: That is the problem. Code I showed is all I have. Next part is what I lack. By first and last I mean there is a DTO object created by factoryMethod. And this DTO is generated on each mouse move event. What I need is the first and last of those objects.

Comment: You say "We have a chart that user can drag" - does that mean you have the code that does the drag or not?

Comment: Not. Right now I can only access that value property. Without significant refactoring it is not possible to assess mouse events (cannot get in to details). That is why I decided to try Rx.

Comment: "Assess" or "Access"?

Comment: Right now you need to provide us with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some more looking and adapting existing examples I've managed to come up with a solution that seems to work.

```
public static IObservable<IList<TSource>> FirstAndLast<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan threshold)
{
    return Observable.Create<IList<TSource>>((obs) =>
    {
        return source.GroupByUntil(_ => true,
            g => g.Throttle(threshold).Select(_ => Unit.Default))
            .SelectMany(i => i.ToList().Select(_=> new List<TSource> {_.First(), _.Last()}))
            .Subscribe(obs);
    });
}
```

Comment: There is clearly a relationship between the text in your question and the answer you've posted, but the code in the question just seems random. Can you please edit the question with a [mcve] so that the question and answer are both clear and related?